# Elasticsearch Ngrams: Unexpected behavior for autocomplete

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's a simplification of what I have:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title": "Quick Foxes" 
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "title": "Quick Fuxes" 
}

PUT my_index/_doc/3
{
  "title": "Foxes Quick" 
}

PUT my_index/_doc/4
{
  "title": "Foxes Slow" 
}
```

I am trying to search for `Quick Fo` to test the autocomplete:

```
 GET my_index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "title": {
            "query": "Quick Fo", 
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is that this query also returns `Foxes Quick` where I expected 'Quick Foxes'

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Quick Foxes"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Foxes Quick"   <<<----- WHY???
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What can I tweak so that I can query a classic "autocomplete" where "Quick Fo" surely won't return "Foxes Quick"..... but only "Quick Foxes"?

**---- ADDITIONAL INFO -----------------------**

This worked for me:

```
PUT my_index1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
          "search_analyzer": "standard" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT my_index1/_doc/1
{
  "text": "Quick Brown Fox" 
}

PUT my_index1/_doc/2
{
  "text": "Quick Frown Fox" 
}


PUT my_index1/_doc/3
{
  "text": "Quick Fragile Fox" 
}


GET my_index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "quick br", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is due to your search analyzer **autocomplete_search**, in which you are using the lowercase tokenizer, so your search term **Quick Fo** will be divided into 2 terms, **quick** and **fo** (note lowercase) and will be matched against the tokens generated using the `autocomplete analyzer` on your indexed docs.

Now title **Foxes Quick** uses `autocomplete analyzer` and will be having both **quick** and **fo** tokens, hence it matches with the search term tokens.

you can simply use the [_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API, to check the tokens generated for your documents and as well as for your search term, to understand it better.

Please refer official ES doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html on how to implement the autocomplete, they also use different search time analyzer, but there is a certain limitation to it and can't solve all the use-cases(**esp. if you have docs like yours**), hence I implemented it using some other design, which is based on the business requirements.

Hope I was clear on explaining why it's returning the second doc in your case.

**EDIT:** **Also in your case, IMO [Match phrase prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) would be more useful.**